# How to do a complex login with Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

[Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

I'm trying to login to Paychex's Time and Labor website with Python to keep track of my hours automatically.

What I did so far was login to Paychex using Chrome, looked at the various requests in the "Network" tab of the Developer Tools, and translate the requests into Python Requests format:

```py
import requests
import json
import sys

USER = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'

IMAGE_URL = 'https://landing.paychex.com/ssologin/Login.aspx/GetSecurityImage'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://landing.paychex.com/ssologin/Login.aspx/ProcessLogin'
LOGINFCC_URL = 'https://landing.paychex.com/ssologin/login.fcc'

def main():
    session = requests.session()

    # Get security image
    data = { 'enteredUsername': USER }
    session.headers.update({
        'Origin': 'https://landing.paychex.com',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
        'Referer': 'https://landing.paychex.com/ssologin/login.aspx',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    })
    r = session.post(IMAGE_URL, data=json.dumps(data))

    data = { 'eu': USER, 'ep': PASSWORD }
    session.headers.update({
        'Host': 'landing.paychex.com',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': '34',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
        'Origin':' https://landing.paychex.com',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Referer':' https://landing.paychex.com/ssologin/login.aspx',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    })
    r = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=json.dumps(data))

    session.headers.update({
        'Host': 'landing.paychex.com',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length': '653',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Origin': 'https://landing.paychex.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Referer': 'https://landing.paychex.com/ssologin/login.aspx',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    })
    data = {
        '__LASTFOCUS': '',
        '__EVENTTARGET': '',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
        '__VIEWSTATE': '',
        '__EVENTVALIDATION': '',
        'SMENC': 'ISO-8859-1',
        'SMLOCALE': 'US-EN',
        'target': '/LandingRedirect.aspx',
        'USER': USER,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
    }
    r = session.post(LOGINFCC_URL, data=data) # Returns "Welcome USER" page. Successful login.

    session.headers.update({
        'Host': 'timeandlabor.paychex.com',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    })

    # Should return time and labor page, but instead it hangs here until connection is reset by peer.
    r = session.get('https://timeandlabor.paychex.com/secure/EmployeeHome.aspx')

    print(r.content.decode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I that understand many of the headers are redundant. The third request returns the "Welcome, Name!" page, so it's definitely logging in successfully. The problem arises when I try to request the time and labor page with a GET (near the bottom). It just hangs there until the connection is reset. What am I doing wrong?

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 319, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 493, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 321, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1172, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 313, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 371, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 746, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 618, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 327, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 543, in urlopen
    raise MaxRetryError(self, url, e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='timeandlabor.paychex.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /secure/EmployeeHome.aspx (Caused by <class 'ConnectionResetError'>: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "paychex.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
  File "paychex.py", line 84, in main
    r = session.get('https://timeandlabor.paychex.com/secure/EmployeeHome.aspx')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 375, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='timeandlabor.paychex.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
/secure/EmployeeHome.aspx (Caused by <class 'ConnectionResetError'>: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)
```

Using Python 3.4.2.